# add or delete data from structure

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have the following code:
(I kept only the relevant part for my question)

```
        // Structure
        struct first_list {
            char firstname[100];
            struct first_list * next;
        };
        struct last_list {
            char lastname[100];
            struct last_list * next;
        };

        void verify_name()
        {
            char firstname[100];
            char lastname[100];
            struct first_list * curr_first = loaded_first;
            struct last_list * curr_last = loaded_last;

        /////////// this part was added by me
            while( curr_last != NULL )
            {
                strncpy(lastname, curr_last->lastname, sizeof( lastname ) - 1 );
                valid = validate_name(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),firstname);
                if(valid < 1)
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s is VALID\n", lastname);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s is invalid\n", lastname);

                curr_last = curr_last->next; //this is used for removing current record

            }
            printf( "LastName validation complete\n" );
            break;
        /////////// end of part added by me

            while( curr_last != NULL && curr_first != NULL )
            {
                strncpy(firstname, curr_first->firstname, sizeof( firstname ) - 1 );
                strncpy(lastname, curr_last->lastname, sizeof( lastname ) - 1 );

                ////////////////////////////////
                //// irrelevant code (functions)
                ////////////////////////////////

                if( curr_first->next == NULL && curr_last->next != NULL)
                {
                    curr_last = curr_last->next;
                    curr_first = loaded_first;
                }
                else 
                    curr_first = curr_first->next;
            }
        }
```

so, I added a new function to validate lastnames before the function which validates firstnames and lastnames at the same time (to optimize the whole process). The problem is that if I remove the break command I get an error cause last_list is empty after validation.

***How can I keep only the valid last names in the structure because right now when is moving to the next record it is deleting the current one until loop is complete(NULL) ??***

Comment: Warning: `strncpy` is unsafe.  You need to null-terminate after using it, because it does not do this itself.

Comment: I posted only the relevant code for my question which is about structure.

Comment: you still should take an advice from a gentleman and that's why he posted it as a comment since it's not relevant to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do in your first loop is:

```
struct last_list * prev = NULL;
struct last_list * next = NULL;
while (curr_last != NULL)
{
  next = curr_last->next;
  strncpy(lastname, curr_last->lastname, sizeof(lastname) - 1);
  lastname[sizeof(lastname) - 1] = 0;
  valid = validate_name(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),firstname);
  if(valid < 1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is VALID\n", lastname);
    prev = curr_last;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is invalid\n", lastname);
    if (prev == NULL)
      loaded_last = curr_last->next;  //this is used for removing when current is first record
    else
      prev->next = curr_last->next; //this is used for removing current record from mid-list
    free(curr_last); //Freeing should be needed but depends on how you built your list.
  }
  curr_last = next;
}
curr_last = loaded_last;
```

This will remove your `curr_last` element from the list and retain only valid lastnames in it.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it but it saves only the last good last_name after validation. It doesn't save all of them.

Comment: Sorry I thought that was your need to save only the validating ones as your question was "How can I keep only the valid last names in the structure?"

Answer (score 0):

You've "consumed" the list with the (e.g.) cur_last->next within the loop so you will need to reinitialise cur_first and cur_last to point to the start of the lists or have a single loop that performs both functions

Comment: cannot have a single loop to perform the both functions. I must use 2 loops